# Por que me da error al realizar la compra en paypal y por que no puedo guardar los datos ala base de dato

Tags: javascript, python, django, paypal

Soy nuevo en el SDK de paypal y lo estoy utilizando en una aplicacion de django para realizar compras, el problema es que no me guarda los datos.

Error Content-Security-Policy al realizar pago en PayPal: ¿Cómo solucionar y permitir eval en la política de seguridad de contenido?

Estoy integrando la pasarela de pago de PayPal en mi sitio web y he enfrentado un problema con la política de seguridad de contenido (`Content-Security-Policy`). Al realizar un pago, obtengo el siguiente error en la consola del navegador:

> Content-Security-Policy: Las opciones para esta página han bloqueado la carga de un recurso en eval (script-src).

Investigando, parece que este error está relacionado con la ejecución de `eval` en mi código, y sospecho que es parte de la respuesta que obtengo de PayPal.

Adjunto está el objeto que recibo de PayPal después de una transacción exitosa:

Esto es lo me me muestra en la consola al realizar la transación:

```
{
  id: "45003689WH1339242",
  intent: "CAPTURE",
  status: "COMPLETED",
  purchase_units: [...],
  payer: { ... },
  create_time: "2023-11-15T18:16:12Z",
  update_time: "2023-11-15T18:16:46Z",
  links: [...]
}
```

Para realizar pruevas en una cuenta sandbox.

```
    <script>
        function getCookie(name){
            let cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== ''){
              const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
              for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++){
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                if(cookie.substring(0,name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                  cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                  break;
                }
              }
            }

            return cookieValue;
        }


        var cantidad = "{{ grand_total }}"
        var url = "{% url 'pagos' %}"
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        var orderID = "{{ order.order_number }}"
        var payment_method = 'PayPal';

        paypal.Buttons({
            // Finalize the transaction on the server after payer approval
          createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: cantidad
                    }
                }]
            });
          },
          onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData){
                // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
               console.log(orderData);
               sendData();
               
               function sendData(){
                fetch(url, {
                  method : "POST",
                  headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "X-CSRFToken" : csrftoken,
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                    orderID: data.orderID,
                    transID: orderData.id,
                    payment_method: payment_method,
                    status: orderData.status
                  }),
                })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then(data => console.log(data))
               }
            })
          }

        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
        
    </script>
```

Pero al realizar la ejecucion de manda estos errores en la consola.

> ```
>     Object { success: false, error_message: "Orden matching query does not exist." }
>
>     Content-Security-Policy: Las opciones para esta página han bloqueado la carga de un recurso en eval (script-src).
> ```

En mi vista lo tengo configurado de esta manera.

```
    def pagos(request):
    try:
        body = json.loads(request.body)
        print(f'user: {request.user}, esta_ordenado: {False}, numero_orden: {body["orderID"]}')
        orden = Orden.objects.get(user=request.user, esta_ordenado=False, numero_orden=body['orderID'])

        pago = Pago(
            user=request.user,
            pago_id=body['transID'],
            metodo_pago=body['payment_method'],
            cantidad_id=orden.orden_total,
            estado=body['status'],
        )
        pago.save()

        orden.pago = pago
        orden.esta_ordenado = True
        orden.save()

        # Devuelve una respuesta JSON indicando éxito
        response_data = {'success': True}
        return JsonResponse(response_data)

    except Exception as e:
        # En caso de error, devolver una respuesta JSON con un mensaje de error
        response_data = {'success': False, 'error_message': str(e)}
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

Este es mi modelo al que tengo que enviar los datos:

```
    class Pago(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Cuenta, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pago_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    metodo_pago = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cantidad_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    creado_en = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pago_id
```

Si alguine fuera tan amable de ayudarme.